# Java Robot MouseMove is inconsistent

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

I have this code:

```
Robot mov = null;
try {
     mov = new Robot();
} catch (AWTException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
if(movedy!=0&&movedx!=0) {
    mov.mouseMove(300, 300);

}
```

And on my PC, IT never moves the mouse to the correct location. Interestingly though, it works on my Mac. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This would most likely point to your resolution. (300, 300) is not going to be the same location on two different computers if they do not have the same resolution. I would use relative location by pulling in the location of another component or manually change (300, 300) to something closer to what you need.